# Issue with using multiple country-tags and ignore lists

Tags: discussion, country-tags

I've also [posted an answer about this issue on the main meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334/what-should-happen-with-a-question-that-has-both-ignored-and-interesting-tags/61590#61590) site, but I thought I'd get some opinions here as well.

I'm British, and don't have an interest in, nor do I feel qualified to answer, US or Canada -specific questions. I therefore chose to ignore both the `[united-states]` and `[canada]` country tags. This means questions, for example, about UK-Canada transfers are faded. I thought adding my local country-tag, `[united-kingdom]` to my favourites list would resolve the issue, but the ignored list takes precedence so I still skim over those questions.

Is this something that affects a lot of users, or is it just me? What would you do in this situation?

Comment: Wait, are ignored tags actually hidden now?  Or are you referring to faded visual treatment?  Regardless, this is basically the reason I have no ignored tags.

Comment: @George Marian - sorry, they're just faded, and whilst on most sites this means I don't bother, here it provides just enough distinction to cause me to skim over them

Comment: Side FYI that doesn't help solve the problem:  there *is* a "Hide Ignored Tags" option in the *prefs* section of one's account that changes the treatment from faded to gone.  For that to even be useful, prioritizing interesting over ignored is a must.